# Ad Hoc Deployment Issue: putpkt: write failed: Broken pipe

Tags: iphone, deployment, adhoc

I have a beta version of my app developed, and I'm looking to put it on a few friend's iPhones for testing purposes.  I've gone through the Ad Hoc deployment steps at the Developer Portal, and I've also followed the instructions here: http://www.talentgrouplabs.com/blog/archive/2008/11/10/iphone-sdk-mobile-provisioning-0xe800003a-0xe8000001.aspx. When I try to compile the app with the Ad Hoc settings selected I get a "putpkt: write failed: Broken pipe." error logged to the console.  The app seems to get installed, and it starts to run, because I see the first screen for a second.  However, then it crashes and exits.  I'm at a loss.  Any thoughts?  Here is what is output to the console:

```
  [Session started at 2009-01-28 21:59:35 -0500.]
  Loading program into debugger…
  Warning - No location found for "AreasTableViewController.m:84"
  GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-963) (Sun Nov  2 03:13:07 UTC 2008)
  Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
  welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
  Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
  There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
  This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty       /dev/ttys000
  Program loaded.
  target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-6714-88
  Switching to remote protocol
  mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
  mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
  mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
  sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
  run
  Running…
  putpkt: write failed: Broken pipe.
  putpkt: write failed: Broken pipe.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's essentially an internal error in Xcode's ability to talk to your phone.  It doesn't mean you've done anything wrong, it's a bug in the development system.  It'll go away after quitting and restarting Xcode, and possibly after restarting your Mac.  I haven't seen the error in a while-- it's possible that other voodoo like removing the app from the phone may be necessary.

Comment: Reminds me of fixing old Windows problems - Cross your fingers and reboot!

Comment: This kind of thing is the iPhone developer hokey pokey. Do a bunch of stuff that doesn't seem necessary, and with any luck things will start working again. Fortunately it's a lot less common than it used to be.

Comment: It makes it especially tough when you are trying to test lightweight migration between versions of an app! Can't figure out how to do it as I get this error EVERY time

Answer (score 1):

I found this online and it worked for me.  Just re-starting xcode was not enough.

1. quit Xcode (and therefor the GDB it is running)
2. unplug device
3. delete app from device (hold icon till x appears)
4. turn off device
5. turn on device
6. plug in device (if itunes wants to sync, let it finish)
7. launch Xcode

Answer (score 1):

Just put off your device and switch it on again, now run your application, it will work proper.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs across this, there appears to be a bug with Xcode 4.2 (beta) and iOS 5 (beta) that doesn't allow me to run any app with an ad hoc profile.

When I switched it back to the developer provisioning profile everything worked correctly.